Total boundness & precompactness on Metric Space
Hi i'm studying an introduction course to Functional Analysis and i'm little confusing about the relation between the Total Boundness and Precompactness of space on world of Metric Spaces
For clarity i report the definitions that i adopt:
Def(1)[Totally Bounded (metric) spaces] A metric space  $(M, d)$ is said to be Totally Bounded iff , $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists S_{\epsilon} \subset M$ such that $card(S) < \infty$ and {$B_{\epsilon}(s)$}$_{s\in S}$  is an open cover for M.
Def(2)[Precompact (topological) spaces] Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, let $P \subset X$, P is said to be Precompact (on X) iff $cl_X(P)$ is compact.
And some results that i'm able to prove:
Thm(1): Let $(X, d)$ a metric space, X is Totally Bounded iff every sequence in X admits an a subsequence that is Cauchy (In some text i found this as def of 'sequentially precompact').
Thm(2): Let $(M, d)$ a metric Totally Bounded, Then every subspace of $M$ is Totally Bounded (of we consider it as a metric space with inducted metric obv).
Thm(3): Let $(M, d)$ a complete metric space, Then $X \subset M$ is compact iff it is Totally Bounded and Closed.

So i have several questions:
\
(1) Some texts call $S_{\epsilon}$ of def(1) an "finite $\epsilon$-net", however i know the notion of $\epsilon$-net as reported here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delone_set, and in this sense it seems to me that is wrong. But on the other hand i found also these definition: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Net_(Metric_Space).
(2) Taking my definitions, exist some result about equivalence of precompact and sequencial precompact notion on metric space?
(3)I read on https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/precompact+space that on every uniform space the (generalized) notion of Total Boundness is equivalent to Precompactness, i would like to prove these fact restricted on metric space, but i don't found any material about it. Maybe is something extremely easly to prove on more generally context?
(4)I would appreciate it very much an a example in which there is total boundness but not precompactness or viceversa.

In your third proposition, you end with "(with subspace topology obviously)" to me nothing about this sentence is obvious, most notably the fact that the "with" in this sentence is referring to the property of being "totally bounded" which is not a topological property, but rather a property of metric spaces, and in fact some topological spaces can be metrized to yield a metric space which is totally bounded, and in a way which is not, so I think it is best to ommit any mention of the topology. Metric subspaces are perfectly understood without it.

You're right, i was inaccurate. When i say that a subspace of a metric space Is totally bounded i mean that we had to consider the subspace as a metric space with metric inducted. I said 'obv' beacause in same sense these are 'natural' choice when we talk about 'subspace' of a space with some topological property

I think your definition of totally bounded should have $\text{card}(S_\epsilon)<\infty$, not $\text{card}(S_\epsilon)\color{red}{\leq}\infty$.
I'll go ahead and say that in all definitions below, I know some people who would use open balls $$B_\epsilon(s):=\{x\in M:d(s,x)<\epsilon\},$$ while some would used the closed balls $$D_\epsilon(s):=\{x\in M:d(x,s)\leqslant \epsilon\}.$$   But be aware that this inconsistency in terminology may exist. In fact, in the link to Delone set that you provided, I'm not even sure if they are using open or closed balls, because they say an $R$-coverage is such that every point is "within distance $R$". I'm not sure if that means $<R$ or $\leqslant R$. But it usually doesn't matter in terms of the underlying properties, as long as everything is clearly stated.
I and all of my colleagues would use $\epsilon$-net to mean: $S\subset M$ is an $\epsilon$-net (for $M$) if $M=\cup_{s\in S}B_\epsilon(s)$. (open balls are used). This agrees with $\epsilon$-\emph{covering} in the Delone set wikipedia you linked. So you are correct that these definitions of $\epsilon$-net do not agree.  What I would call an $\epsilon$-net is what the Delone set link calls an $\epsilon$-covering.
In the Delone set link, they also define an $\epsilon$-packing. Let's say $S\subset M$ is an $\epsilon$-packing if for any $s,s'\in S$ with $s\neq s'$, $d(s,s')/2\geqslant \epsilon$. In that link, they then define an $\epsilon$-net to be a set which is both an $\epsilon$-coverage and an $\epsilon/$-packing, which means that

for any $x\in M$, there exists $s\in S$ such that $d(s,x)<\epsilon$, and

for any $s,s'\in S$ with $s\neq s'$, $d(s,s')\geqslant \epsilon$.


Here is the relationship. Let's use "$\epsilon$-net $I$" to mean an $\epsilon$-net according to the first definition. Let's use "$\epsilon$-net $II$" to mean an $\epsilon$-net according to the Delone set link.
Suppose that $S$ is an $\epsilon$-net $II$. Then it is a minimal $\epsilon$-net $I$. Obviously it's an $\epsilon$-net $I$. But if we take $S$ and remove $s'$, then the remaining set is no longer an $\epsilon$-net $I$, because $s'$ is not distance $<\epsilon$ to any of the remaining points.
On the other hand, if we take a minimal $\epsilon$-net $I$, then for any $s'\in S$, since $S\setminus \{s'\}$ is not an $\epsilon$-net $I$, there exists $t\in M$ such that $d(s,t)\geqslant \epsilon$ for all $s\in S\setminus \{s'\}$. Since $S$ is an $\epsilon$-net $I$, $t$ must be a member of $B_\epsilon(s)$.

The link you give to nLab says that a set is precompact if its completion is compact. This is not the usual definition of precompact, and in fact I've never heard this definition before. I do not believe it is widely used. Usually precompact is defined so that $S$ is preacompact iff $\text{closure}(S)$ is compact. This definition is used for general topological spaces (including non-metric spaces, where "completion" might not make sense). So I'll address all of your remaining questions with that in mind as the definition of "precompact." However, I will not use the term "precompact", because I do not believe this is a widely used definition.

If $M$ is complete and $S$ is a subset of $M$, then the closure of $S$ in $M$ is canonically isometrically identifiable with the completion of $S$ (in particular, $S$ is complete iff it's closed in $M$). So if the ambient space $M$ is complete, the completion of $S$ is compact iff the closure of $S$ is compact, and the two definitions agrees in that case. However, if $M$ is not complete, the closure of $S$ in $M$ may also be not complete (for example, if $M$ is not complete, then $S=M$ is closed but not complete), and will therefore not be compact (according to the following theorem).
Here is a theorem: Let $M$ be a metric space (with implied metric $d$). Then $M$ is compact iff it is sequentially compact iff the space is complete and totally bounded.
It's pretty easy to see that $S$ is totally bounded iff its completion is. By definition, the completion is complete, and so according to the preceding theorem, the completion is compact iff it is totally bounded (iff $S$ is totally bounded). You can probably find proofs of the preceding theorem. If not, leave a comment and I'll say more.
If your definition of "sequentially precompact" is that $S$ is sequentially precompact iff its completion is compact (which, again, I do not believe is a standard definition, but I do believe it is what you're asking about because of the nLab link). We can use the preceding theorem to deduce that this is equivalent to "having compact completion", which is again equivalent to total boundedness.

Using the nLab definition of precompactness, they are equivalent, as stated above. Using the usual definition of precompact (having compact closure), take $M=(0,1)$ with the usual metric. Then $M$ is totally bounded but not precompact, because its closure (which is $M$ itself) is not compact. This is because the sequence $(1/2,1/3,1/4,\ldots)$ has no convergent subsequence. Alternatively, pick a sequence $0=t_0<t_1<\ldots$ with $\lim_n t_n=1$ and let $I_n$ be disjoint open intervals such that the length of $I_n$ is $$\frac{1}{2}\max_{1\leqslant m\leqslant n+1} t_m-t_{m-1}.$$   Then $$\{(t_{n-1},t_n):n=1,2,\ldots\}\cup \{I_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ is an open cover of $(0,1)$ with no proper (and therefore no finite) subcover.


Your 2. is amusing as I have had the opposite experience: I have always seen precompactness introduced as either total boundedness or as "the Hausdorff completion is compact". What OP and you are calling precompactness is something I always have seen being called "relative compactness".

Yes, your right it was a typo.

Thank you very much for the very detail answer! (1) And (4) for me now are very clear!

For (2) i had to study more things about completion, but all these facts now seems to me more clear.

About (1): I agree to the statement "$\epsilon$-net II is 'minimal' as $\epsilon$-net I, i.e
if we remove any element it's no longer a $\epsilon$-net I", therefore in my opinion this is not a natural notion of minimality relation between these two objects. For say that  "The minimal $\epsilon$-net I is a $\epsilon$-net II" we have to hope that is true the followiing statement: "Let $S$ a $\epsilon$-net I, suppose that if we remove any element from $S$, it is no longer an $\epsilon$-net I, Then $S$ is an $\epsilon$-net II".

Therefore, i try to prove it , but noe it seem to me false. The crucial point that i understand is that an $\epsilon$-net I always exists, conversely an $\epsilon$-net II doesn't exist for every $\epsilon$

So maybe we can hope that : "Let $S$ a $\epsilon$-net I, suppose that if we remove any element from $S$, it is no longer an $\epsilon$-net I, Then $S$ is an $\epsilon$-net II, IF EXISTS". Therefore It still seems false to me, i think that the only right things is that exisist an algoritm to transform an $\epsilon$-net I to an $\epsilon$-net II (if exists)

@P.P.Tuong Interesting! Thank you for telling me. I have always encountered "precompact" and "relative compactness" as pure synonyms.
What is the context/discipline/subject area in which "precompact" is defined in terms of completions? I have only ever heard "precompact" as a topological notion, a generality in which "completion" isn't defined.

@ManuelBonanno The notions of $\epsilon$-packing and $\epsilon$-covering are kind of getting at opposing properties. Informally, the set $S$ being an $\epsilon$-packing means the set $S$ is "not too dense" in $M$. The set $S$ being an $\epsilon$-covering means it is "sufficiently dense" in $M$. The notion of $\epsilon$-net ($II$) is right there in the middle. It has enough to be within $\epsilon$ of every point of $M$, without having extra, unnecessary things. So in that sense, one often finds notions related to $\epsilon$-net $II$ as maximal packings/minimal coverings.

Suppose that $T$ is an $\epsilon$-covering of $M$. Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a subset of the power set of $M$ such that 1. every member of $\mathcal{S}$ is an $\epsilon$-covering of $M$, and 2. $\mathcal{S}$ is totally ordered by inclusion (that is, for $S,S'\in \mathcal{S}$, either $S\subset S'$ or $S'\subset S$), and 3. $S\subset T$ for every $S\in \mathcal{S}$. Then $\cap\mathcal{S}$ is also an $\epsilon$-covering and a subset of $T$. Therefore by Zorn's lemma, every $\epsilon$-covering has a minimal $\epsilon$-subcovering.

Given that every metric space has an $\epsilon$-covering (namely, the whole space), it also has at least one minimal $\epsilon$-covering.
If we assume the existence of a finite $\epsilon$-covering, then there is a finite, minimal $\epsilon$-covering.

However, in terms of understanding total boundedness of a metric space (and why it's equivalent to the completion being compact/sequentially compact), I believe you said you have a good understanding of that now. If so, I think the notion of $\epsilon$-net II is unrelated to this. Perhaps it's worth a separate question to try to understand the relationship between the notions and whether minimality (wrt inclusion) is really the key connection. I must be honest, at this point I don't know.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@user469053 There is of course the context of uniform spaces, and then there is also anything that is built on top of uniform spaces, for example: topological groups, topological rings, topological vector spaces, etc.

Thank you. I'm a functional analyst, so TVSs are some of my favorite things. But uniform spaces have been a blind spot for me for some time.

So assuming Def(2) for precompactness, we could say that in metric space $(M, d)$:
Precompact $\subsetneq$ Totally Bounded
indeed is easly to see that Compact implies Totally Bounded, but Precompact is a subset of it's closure, and finally every subset of Totally Bounded is Totally bunded, then every Precompact is Totally Bounded.
Moreover any examples on 4. of the previous answer proof that the inclusion is strictly.

Let $S\subset M$ be a set and let $\overline{S}$ be the closure. Then according to definition 2, $S$ is precompact iff $\overline{S}$ is compact iff $\overline{S}$ is complete and totally bounded. But $\overline{S}$ is totally bounded iff $S$ is. Perhaps the most natural way of saying that $\overline{S}$ is complete would be to say that the completion of $S$ is contained in $M$.

For the last statement, we need to prove a context in which the completion of $S$ is comparable to $M$ (ie an ambient space in which saying that the completion of $S$ is contained in $M$ makes sense). There is a canonical way to construct the completion (call it $M_0$) of $M$, and a canonical isometric embedding $j:M\to M_0$. So we can consider $M$ as a subset of $M_0$ by identifying $M$ with $j(M)$. It is also the case that we can consider the completion $S_0$ of $S$ as a subset of the completion of $M$. It is in this context that we can ask whether $S_0\subset j(M)$.

Another way to characterize this would be to say that every Cauchy sequence in $S$ converges in $M$.
